# How to compare firebase timestamps?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have cloud function code code like this:

```
console.log(`ts: ${(element.get('expire') as admin.firestore.Timestamp).toDate().toUTCString()} now: ${admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toDate().toUTCString()}`)
const greater = (element.get('expire') as admin.firestore.Timestamp) > admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
const lower = (element.get('expire') as admin.firestore.Timestamp) < admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
console.log(`greater: ${greater} lower: ${lower}`)
```

In console:

> ts: Mon, 08 Apr 2019 20:59:59 GMT now: Fri, 08 Mar 2019 20:19:18 GMT
>
> greater: false lower: false

So how correctly compare to Timestamps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by comparing the [seconds](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/Timestamp#seconds) and [nanoseconds](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/Timestamp#nanoseconds) properties on the Timestamp objects.  Or, to make it simpler, and you don't need nanosecond precision, you can just compare the results of the results of their [toMillis()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/Timestamp#toMillis) values.

Comment: Thanks. This is the only solution to compare milliseconds.

Comment: is it possible to create an index for firebase timestamps?

Comment: New URL: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/timestamp#_google_cloud_firestore_Timestamp_toMillis_member_1_

Answer (score 20):

As of SDK Version 7.10.0, you can directly compare Timestamp objects with the JavaScript arithmetic inequality comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`).

To check if two Timestamp objects are temporally identical you must use the `isEqual` property ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#isequal)). Comparing with `==` or `===` will not check for temporal equality- returning `false` if comparing different object instances.

[SDK release notes here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7100_-_march_5_2020).

Code snippet pulled [from corresponding GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2632):

```
a = new Timestamp(1, 1)
b = new Timestamp(2, 2)
console.log(a < b) // true
console.log(b < a) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, we can use the method `valueOf()` to compare Timestamp. [Here the reference of valueOf](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#valueof)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32474690)

Answer (score 1):

I can find no documentation for it other than the [code itself](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/src/lite-api/timestamp.ts#L147), but it is worth noting that `Timestamp` appears to have a `_compareTo` instance method (at least in my current running version v8.10.1) which returns the sort-friendly -1, 1, and 0 comparison values.

```js
const a = Timestamp.now();

// Some time later
const b = Timestamp.now();

console.log(b._compareTo(a)); // 1
console.log(a._compareTo(b)); // -1
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried turning your Timestamps into a Date object to be able to then just compare Dates instead of Timestamps?

For example:

```
const greater = new Date(element.get('expire') as admin.firestore.Timestamp) > new Date();
const lower = new Date(element.get('expire') as admin.firestore.Timestamp) < new Date();
```